# SingularityGS: Why is the box-shadow missing at alpha and omega edges of of grid?

Tags: css, compass-sass, clearfix

Using Singularitygs 1.3.0 together Drupal Omega 4

I have some blocks laid out in a grid, each of which has a box-shadow applied. For some reason the box-shadow effect does not display at alpha or omega edges, adjacent to the wrapping container. Please see pictiure below.

[image: Enlarged picture]

I get the desired effect in Sassmeister http://sassmeister.com/gist/fcd3a013ab50e62743a4 and I am puzzled why this is not working with my theme.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you've got `overflow: hidden` on the container.

---

`@MrPaulDriver`, the asker:

Thank you `@lolmaus` (once again). This turned out to be because I was using `@include clearfix` on the container. What was needed was `@pie-clearfix`. Documentation can be found here

http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/utilities/general/clearfix/